Eccentric: how to pronounce
There's a whole continent that pronounces it like:
https://youtu.be/MhtrM4fcnBI?t=270
What's up with that?
I asked the staff in my gym today. They said these were two different words that are spelled the same but pronounced differently:

Eccentric: an adjective to describe a weirdo.
E-centric: Something a muscle does.

Say what?

The video was from Aus, but I now see that the US isn't different. In fact, can anyone show me a single training-related video where eccentric is pronounced correctly?

Voted to migrate to ELL (where it belongs, and where it will presumably be closed as a duplicate! :)

You should not seek English advice in a gym! I think that 'British geezer' simply doesn't know how to pronounce the word 'eccentric'. I gather it is not unknown in gym (and medical!) circles. It's Eksentrik. The 'cc'  is said the same as in 'success'. I did date a rather posh girl from Sussex who said 'essentric', but I found it very easy to forgive that.

It seems, maybe, it's a 'coach' thing, and possibly an American/British thing (but that was a Cockney geezer in the video).

Dear Zohar, you mention, in your question,  'a whole continent', and I agree that  it seems many Americans say it that way, but your video shows a man with a strong Cockney (British working class) accent. Last time I checked, the island of Great Britain was not a continent!

He is from Perth: https://www.paultwyman.com.au/contact-us

clearly australian ... and he is NOT saying ecccentric. In context he is using the word as a noun so must be ecentric, which seems to mean an eccentric (in the literal sense in this case) person or thing. Not normal in BrE though.
